# CSV columns mismatch in LibreOffice, but not in Excel; can't import to R

Tags: r, csv

This is a strange thing that has just begun happening:
Suddenly, I cant import .csv files into R using `read.csv`.

I noticed they open normally in Excel, but not in R. They are UTF-8.

I think it has to do with how these first few rows are handled, possibly. See the picture below.

[image]

Any help in resolving this is greatly appreciated.

```
readLines("~1_ShapeXC_N30_3.3_2021-04-25_21h4406175.csv", n=10)
 [1] "X Scale,Y Scale,key_resp_999.keys,key_resp_999.corr,key_resp_999.rt,key_resp_10.keys,key_resp_10.corr,key_resp_10.rt,prelim2loop.thisRepN,prelim2loop.thisTrialN,prelim2loop.thisN,prelim2loop.thisIndex,prelim2loop.ran,participant,session,date,expName,psychopyVersion,OS,frameRate,PROLIFIC_PID,STUDY_ID,SESSION_ID,key_resp_11.keys,key_resp_11.corr,key_resp_11.rt,prelim3loop.thisRepN,prelim3loop.thisTrialN,prelim3loop.thisN,prelim3loop.thisIndex,prelim3loop.ran,readybegin235loop.thisRepN,readybegin235loop.thisTrialN,readybegin235loop.thisN,readybegin235loop.thisIndex,readybegin235loop.ran,key_resp_xp.keys,key_resp_xp.rt,conf_rating.keys,conf_rating.rt,col_diff.keys,col_diff.rt,conf_rating_2.keys,conf_rating_2.rt,trials_5.thisRepN,trials_5.thisTrialN,trials_5.thisN,trials_5.thisIndex,trials_5.ran,ImageFile,Manipulation,spacetocontinue_3.keys,spacetocontinue_3.rt,trials_6.thisRepN,trials_6.thisTrialN,trials_6.thisN,trials_6.thisIndex,trials_6.ran,trials_10.thisRepN,trials_10.thisTrialN,trials_10.thisN,trials_10.thisIndex,trials_10.ran"
 [2] "0.05,0.05,space,0,106.066415,l,0,27.175845,0,0,0,0,1,1,001,2021-04-25_21h44.06.175,ShapeXC,"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 [3] ",,,,,,,,,,,,,1,001,2021-04-25_21h44.06.175,ShapeXC_N30_3.3,2020.2.8,Win32,60,"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 [4] ",,,,,,,,,,,,,1,001,2021-04-25_21h44.06.175,ShapeXC_N30_3.3,2020.2.8,Win32,60,"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
 [5] ",,,,,,,,,,,,,1,001,2021-04-25_21h44.06.175,ShapeXC_N30_3.3,2020.2.8,Win32,60,"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
 [6] ",,,,,,,,,,,,,1,001,2021-04-25_21h44.06.175,ShapeXC_N30_3.3,2020.2.8,Win32,60,"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
 [7] ",,,,,,,,,,,,,1,001,2021-04-25_21h44.06.175,ShapeXC_N30_3.3,2020.2.8,Win32,60,"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 [8] ",,,,,,,,,,,,,1,001,2021-04-25_21h44.06.175,ShapeXC_N30_3.3,2020.2.8,Win32,60,"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
 [9] ",,,,,,,,,,,,,1,001,2021-04-25_21h44.06.175,ShapeXC_N30_3.3,2020.2.8,Win32,60,"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
[10] ",,,,,,,,,,,,,1,001,2021-04-25_21h44.06.175,ShapeXC_N30_3.3,2020.2.8,Win32,60,,"
```

Comment: The fact that they look differently between Calc and Excel suggests that they are not truly CSV (or compatible/compliant CSV). Regardless, why the [tag:r] tag, if all you've demonstrated is that the data imports differently in two other apps? The problem is not R. It might be good to include the literal text from the top few lines of the file (not imported, not rendered, just the literal text).

Comment: Use `readLines("filename.csv", n=10)` and post the results as code. Replace `filename` with the actual name of the file.

Comment: Posted in original comment, thanks. Could it be that there are 'spaces' between 'X' and 'Scale'?